# Vuetify 2.0: How can I achieve this layout from Vuetify 1.5?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Hello!**

I recently started using Vuetify 2.0 and I find myself stuck on something I was able to achieve really easy on Vuetify 1.5. I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Please help me achieve this result from this Vuetify 1.5 template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height class="grey darken-4">
        <v-layout fill-height column wrap>
          <v-flex>
            <v-card height="100%">
              <v-card-title>I fill the whole available vertical space.</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex shrink>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>I'm shrinked to content vertically.</v-card-title>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/uatar/pen/rNaxoVV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `column` is no longer specific to the grid, it's now a generic `flex-column` class instead
- `shrink` should be replaced with `flex-grow-0` which prevents the element from growing but will not allow it to shrink below its original size

Other than that everything works pretty similarly:

```html
<v-container fluid class="fill-height grey darken-4">
  <v-row dense class="fill-height flex-column">
    <v-col>
      <v-card height="100%">
        <v-card-title>I fill the whole available vertical space.</v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col class="flex-grow-0">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>I'm shrinked to content vertically.</v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/abzdMWe?editors=1000

Comment: Many thanks :D As I said in my op, I was missing something: the flex-column class on the row. Have a great day!